# Is it standard to get FTP access when doing freelance web design/dev?

Tags: html, ftp

Is it standard to get FTP access when doing freelance web design/dev?

I'm redesigning one page for a company, does it make sense for me to ask them for FTP access?

Thanks

Comment: why do you need FTP access to do a page redesign?

Comment: I just wanted to leave a comment explaining that, as this is clearly [not a programming question](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions),  I'm voting to close as '[off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask).'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is standard it depends on the requirements of the business.  They might just want for you to hand over the code in which case it wouldn't be needed.  They might want you to look after deployment in which case you would likely need some sort of access to the production machine.  Also don't ask for FTP it is not secure and looks a bit amateurish.  Ask instead for SFTP access more or less the same but it runs over SSH so you get security thrown in for free.